# SQL BETWEEN doesn't SELECT given price range from 2 input filed

Tags: php, sql

unable to SELECT `db` row from price between entered field, i tried with below code when i entered price range for `5000 to 8800` it selects all `db` row from price with first no.5 and 8.

can some one explain whats wrong or do i need any change in code.

**SQL**

```
`prs` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="minimum_price" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="maximum_price" class="form-control">
<input type="submit" class="filter_all">


$(document).ready(function () {
            filter_data();
            function filter_data() {
                $('.filter_data');
                var action = 'fetch_data';
                var minimum_price = $('#minimum_price').val();
                var maximum_price = $('#maximum_price').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "fetch.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        action: action,
                        minimum_price: minimum_price,
                        maximum_price: maximum_price
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.filter_data').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            function get_filter(class_name) {
                var filter = [];
                $('.' + class_name + ':checked').each(function () {
                    filter.push($(this).val());
                });
                return filter;
            }
            $('.filter_all').click(function () {
                filter_data();
            });
        });
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM allpostdata WHERE sts = '1' ";

  if (isset($_POST["minimum_price"], $_POST["maximum_price"]) && !empty($_POST["minimum_price"]) && !empty($_POST["maximum_price"])) {
    $query .= "
     AND prs BETWEEN '" . $_POST["minimum_price"] . "' AND '" . $_POST["maximum_price"] . "'
    ";
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? How does the generated code look like? And a proper warning: this code is widely open to SQL injection

Comment: Question: What do you think will happen if someone makes a request with `minimum_price=' ; DELETE FROM allpostdata; --` ?

Comment: instead of using between operator you can use (>) (<) grater than and less than because of you prs is a varchar  column

Comment: Can U pls echo $query and add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column `prs` is a `varchar` column (i.e. it stores text), and is not a numeric column (e.g. `int` or `money`). So the database software is performing a lexicographical comparison, not a numeric ordering.

- Change your database design to store money/currency values using `money` or as `int` cents/pennies.

  - Do not use floating-point types (like `real`, `float`, `double`, etc) to store monetary values because they are imprecise (read up on how IEEE-754 works).
- Also, as stated, your code is wide-open to SQL Injection attacks. Read here: [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection) and [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)
- Also, I recommend avoiding the `x BETWEEN y AND z` operator because of these reasons:

  - The meaning of `AND` in `BETWEEN` is different to the `AND` logical operator which means you need to carefully format your code so it's readable so people don't confuse the semantics of `AND`, especially when using a non-trivial expression for `y` or `z`.
  - It's not immediately obvious if the `BETWEEN` operator is using inclusive or exclusive bounds.
  - If any of the 3 values can be `NULL` then you need to use separate `IS NULL` comparisons anyway, which results in a hideous query.
  - So always using explicit `y <= x AND x < z` is almost always a better idea IMO.

Comment: i tried `prs int(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',`  and i get `#1067 - Invalid default value for 'prs'`

Comment: before convert type to int be sure set '0' value in the fileds where have empty values

Comment: when i try `0 to 60000` it show all row but when i try `1 to 60000` it does it work, is there any method to solve this.